# How do I find extensions and replace them in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a python function that obtains a list of words from a sentence (string) with extensions. An extension is a repetition of (3 or more) letters in English for emphasis. For instance, the word "bessssst" contains an extension. My function would take a sentence such as "Bob is the bessssst." and return `['besssst']`

At first I tried using regex in python (`re.match('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+')`), but I want the word itself, not just the extension.

Comment: This regular expression would match any word as long as there were at least three letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not optimized and only tried it on a couple of strings.

```
>>> 
>>> pattern = "\s(\w*?(?P<ext>\w)(?P=ext){2,}\w*?)\W"
>>> s1 = "Bob is the bessssst."
>>> s2 = "Bob is the bessssst ."
>>> ext_re = re.compile(pattern)
>>> m = ext_re.search(s1)
>>> m.groups()
('bessssst', 's')
>>> m = ext_re.search(s2)
>>> m.groups()
('bessssst', 's')
>>>
```

[Python Regex Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/)

Comment: After seeing @Matteo Italia's pattern, I think it is better with the \b on either end instead of \s and \W.  I knew there was a word boundary sequence but somehow missed it when I looked at the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You could do..

```
import re

def find_ext(text):
    return re.search(r'(\w*(.)\2{2}\w*)', text).group(1)

s = 'Bob is the bessssst'
find_ext(s)
```

If this confuses you, just use..

```
return re.search(r'(\w*(\w)\2{2}\w*)', text).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you are expecting RegEx, but this one doesnt use RegEx and uses [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
strs = "Bob is the bessssst."
from itertools import groupby
print [str for str in strs.split() for k, g in groupby(str) if len(list(g)) > 2]
```

**Output**

```
['bessssst.']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
re.findall(r'(\b\w*(?P<letter>\w)(?P=letter){2}\w*\b)', yourstring)
```

Comment: Regexps are much more readable as raw strings than manually escaped.

Comment: @abarnert: as you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

i know zero about python or its regex implementation, however try this

```
\w+([a-zA-Z])\1{2}\w*
```